# Slow spatial join on many tables

Tags: postgis, spatial-join, st-intersects, imposm, postgresql-9.5

I try to create a view in an Imposm database for rendering purpose.
This view is merely a copy of the osm_resorts table, but with another column 
 **members_types** that concatenate all the **type** strings from several tables whose geometry intersects the **osm_resorts.geometry**.

The query is as follow:

```
-- ~ CREATE materialized VIEW landuse_resorts AS (
EXPLAIN ANALYSE
SELECT 
    osm_resorts.osm_id as osm_id,
    osm_resorts.name as name,

    array_to_string(array_agg(distinct osm_pistes_ways.type::text) 
    || array_agg(distinct pistes_routes.type::text)
    || array_agg(distinct osm_pistes_area.type::text)
    || array_agg(distinct osm_sport_ways.type::text)
    || array_agg(distinct osm_sport_nodes.type::text)
    ,';') 
    AS members_types,

    osm_resorts.geometry as geometry

FROM 
    osm_resorts

    LEFT JOIN osm_pistes_ways 
        ON osm_resorts.type='winter_sports'
        AND (ST_Within(osm_pistes_ways.geometry,osm_resorts.geometry))
    LEFT JOIN pistes_routes 
        ON osm_resorts.type='winter_sports'
        AND (ST_Within(pistes_routes.geometry,osm_resorts.geometry))
    LEFT JOIN osm_pistes_area 
        ON osm_resorts.type='winter_sports'
        AND (ST_Within(osm_pistes_area.geometry,osm_resorts.geometry))
    LEFT JOIN osm_sport_ways 
        ON osm_resorts.type='winter_sports'
        AND (ST_Within(osm_sport_ways.geometry,osm_resorts.geometry))
    LEFT JOIN osm_sport_nodes 
        ON osm_resorts.type='winter_sports'
        AND (ST_Within(osm_sport_nodes.geometry,osm_resorts.geometry))
GROUP BY 
    osm_resorts.osm_id,
    osm_resorts.name,
    osm_resorts.geometry;
-- ~ );
```

As long as I run this over more than 3 joins, this goes incredibly slow.

Here is for the 5 tables:

```
QUERY PLAN                                                                                  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 GroupAggregate  (cost=2868.90..2873.77 rows=10 width=917) (actual time=774415.129..1905194.056 rows=10 loops=1)
   Group Key: osm_resorts.osm_id, osm_resorts.name, osm_resorts.geometry
   ->  Sort  (cost=2868.90..2869.40 rows=201 width=917) (actual time=774415.038..901108.861 rows=56962779 loops=1)
         Sort Key: osm_resorts.osm_id, osm_resorts.name, osm_resorts.geometry
         Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 55498040kB
         ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=9.06..2861.21 rows=201 width=917) (actual time=1.249..571659.780 rows=56962779 loops=1)
               Join Filter: ((osm_resorts.type)::text = 'winter_sports'::text)
               ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=4.65..679.41 rows=34 width=923) (actual time=1.040..8641.053 rows=726023 loops=1)
                     Join Filter: ((osm_resorts.type)::text = 'winter_sports'::text)
                     ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.43..252.15 rows=11 width=915) (actual time=0.778..34.999 rows=1725 loops=1)
                           Join Filter: ((osm_resorts.type)::text = 'winter_sports'::text)
                           ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.28..118.52 rows=10 width=905) (actual time=0.718..11.725 rows=136 loops=1)
                                 Join Filter: ((osm_resorts.type)::text = 'winter_sports'::text)
                                 ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.14..62.32 rows=10 width=897) (actual time=0.591..5.001 rows=23 loops=1)
                                       Join Filter: ((osm_resorts.type)::text = 'winter_sports'::text)
                                       ->  Seq Scan on osm_resorts  (cost=0.00..2.10 rows=10 width=890) (actual time=0.004..0.014 rows=10 loops=1)
                                       ->  Index Scan using idx_routes_geom on pistes_routes  (cost=0.14..6.01 rows=1 width=2166) (actual time=0.407..0.493 rows=2 loops=10)
                                             Index Cond: (osm_resorts.geometry ~ geometry)
                                             Filter: _st_contains(osm_resorts.geometry, geometry)
                                             Rows Removed by Filter: 0
                                 ->  Index Scan using osm_pistes_area_geom on osm_pistes_area  (cost=0.14..5.61 rows=1 width=1156) (actual time=0.141..0.281 rows=6 loops=23)
                                       Index Cond: (osm_resorts.geometry ~ geometry)
                                       Filter: _st_contains(osm_resorts.geometry, geometry)
                                       Rows Removed by Filter: 1
                           ->  Index Scan using osm_sport_nodes_geom on osm_sport_nodes  (cost=0.15..13.35 rows=1 width=42) (actual time=0.040..0.155 rows=13 loops=136)
                                 Index Cond: (osm_resorts.geometry ~ geometry)
                                 Filter: _st_contains(osm_resorts.geometry, geometry)
                                 Rows Removed by Filter: 7
                     ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on osm_pistes_ways  (cost=4.22..38.80 rows=3 width=317) (actual time=0.100..4.712 rows=421 loops=1725)
                           Recheck Cond: (osm_resorts.geometry ~ geometry)
                           Filter: _st_contains(osm_resorts.geometry, geometry)
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 16
                           Heap Blocks: exact=47575
                           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on osm_pistes_ways_geom  (cost=0.00..4.22 rows=9 width=0) (actual time=0.069..0.069 rows=437 loops=1725)
                                 Index Cond: (osm_resorts.geometry ~ geometry)
               ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on osm_sport_ways  (cost=4.41..64.10 rows=6 width=157) (actual time=0.055..0.729 rows=78 loops=726023)
                     Recheck Cond: (osm_resorts.geometry ~ geometry)
                     Filter: _st_contains(osm_resorts.geometry, geometry)
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 3
                     Heap Blocks: exact=5050902
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on osm_sport_ways_geom  (cost=0.00..4.41 rows=18 width=0) (actual time=0.032..0.032 rows=81 loops=726023)
                           Index Cond: (osm_resorts.geometry ~ geometry)
 Planning time: 0.838 ms
 Execution time: 1907119.041 ms
(44 rows)
```

And here for only 3 joins:

```
                                                                            QUERY PLAN                                                                            
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 GroupAggregate  (cost=507.71..508.50 rows=10 width=899) (actual time=564.802..641.585 rows=10 loops=1)
   Group Key: osm_resorts.osm_id, osm_resorts.name, osm_resorts.geometry
   ->  Sort  (cost=507.71..507.79 rows=31 width=899) (actual time=564.759..589.653 rows=50606 loops=1)
         Sort Key: osm_resorts.osm_id, osm_resorts.name, osm_resorts.geometry
         Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 50728kB
         ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=4.50..506.94 rows=31 width=899) (actual time=1.528..426.207 rows=50606 loops=1)
               Join Filter: ((osm_resorts.type)::text = 'winter_sports'::text)
               ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.28..118.52 rows=10 width=905) (actual time=1.087..5.454 rows=136 loops=1)
                     Join Filter: ((osm_resorts.type)::text = 'winter_sports'::text)
                     ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.14..62.32 rows=10 width=897) (actual time=0.887..1.778 rows=23 loops=1)
                           Join Filter: ((osm_resorts.type)::text = 'winter_sports'::text)
                           ->  Seq Scan on osm_resorts  (cost=0.00..2.10 rows=10 width=890) (actual time=0.008..0.016 rows=10 loops=1)
                           ->  Index Scan using idx_routes_geom on pistes_routes  (cost=0.14..6.01 rows=1 width=2166) (actual time=0.110..0.172 rows=2 loops=10)
                                 Index Cond: (osm_resorts.geometry ~ geometry)
                                 Filter: _st_contains(osm_resorts.geometry, geometry)
                                 Rows Removed by Filter: 0
                     ->  Index Scan using osm_pistes_area_geom on osm_pistes_area  (cost=0.14..5.61 rows=1 width=1156) (actual time=0.072..0.155 rows=6 loops=23)
                           Index Cond: (osm_resorts.geometry ~ geometry)
                           Filter: _st_contains(osm_resorts.geometry, geometry)
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 1
               ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on osm_pistes_ways  (cost=4.22..38.80 rows=3 width=317) (actual time=0.081..2.936 rows=372 loops=136)
                     Recheck Cond: (osm_resorts.geometry ~ geometry)
                     Filter: _st_contains(osm_resorts.geometry, geometry)
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 14
                     Heap Blocks: exact=3394
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on osm_pistes_ways_geom  (cost=0.00..4.22 rows=9 width=0) (actual time=0.051..0.051 rows=386 loops=136)
                           Index Cond: (osm_resorts.geometry ~ geometry)
 Planning time: 0.662 ms
 Execution time: 649.763 ms
(29 rows)
```

I guess I'm able to achieve what I want faster, in a way that doesn't go exponentially slower with the number of table joined, but how ?

Comment: just a minor thing: run an `ANALYZE` on the tables that are bitmap scanned.

Comment: oh, and see how the `Sort Method` writes about 55GB to disk in over 12min.? PostgreSQL doesn't have enough memory available to process the sort. You could try to increase `work_mem' to reduce the disk relocation size; get a read about appropriate sizes in respect to your system.

Comment: Thing is, I don't understand why I need to sort so much data! How could I avoid this?

Comment: The only way I can get ST_Within to use and index is to place "`geom1 && geom2 and`" before each. If the spatial index is more discrimitory, place it before the `type`

Comment: The sort is applied to group aggregate the *.type* columns. Unfortunately, with this query it is necessary. You have one major inefficiency in the plan: both `Bitmap Heap Scans` in significant iteration make for > 25% of the execution time. As I said, you can try running `ANALYZE` on those tables to use `Index Scans` instead. In the End, with about 70% of execution time, it's the grouping and inherit sorting that makes for the long running. The datasets are huge, this is to be expected. It might be worth creating a new table with proper indexes on the respective columns to run the grouping on.

Comment: Hmm, a materialized view looked elegant cause I just needed to refersh it on from time to time to follow OSM update. I ll post a more efficient table creation as an answer, then.

Comment: @yvecai it is, or: it can still be. since you create that view only once (or refresh on updates), just let it be created over night ,). once created, you can create indexes on that view and query it performantly...it is an own table after all.  but I guess you're very well aware of that...

Comment: as a materialized view, it has some benefits for updating the base tables, e.g. the `CONCURRENTLY` option. if planned right, the update process should be faster then than with an own table. not sure here where the pros and cons of each options outweight the other...

Comment: I just have Switzerland and small bit of France in the test DB. So if I need 55gb of disk to sort and group data for 10 rows, such a view is definitely not a solution for a full planet. Rebuilding a new table only take a few seconds.

Comment: @yvecai ah, with 'relocated' I meant it's temporary, of course...bad choice of words. PostgreSQL just can't process the data in-memory at once and needs to cache it during the query.

Answer (score 1):

I post this as an answer, because it's 5000x or 10kX faster to create a new table.
Maybe it will allow somebody to tell me how I could create a similar materialized view that fast:

```
CREATE TABLE test AS SELECT * FROM osm_resorts;

ALTER TABLE test ADD members_types text;

UPDATE test SET members_types = concat_ws(
    ';',
    members_types,
    (SELECT string_agg(distinct pistes_routes.type::text, ';')
        FROM pistes_routes
        WHERE ST_Intersects(pistes_routes.geometry,test.geometry)
    )
);
UPDATE test SET members_types = concat_ws(
    ';',
    members_types,
    (SELECT string_agg(distinct osm_pistes_ways.type::text, ';')
        FROM osm_pistes_ways
        WHERE ST_Intersects(osm_pistes_ways.geometry,test.geometry)
    )
);
UPDATE test SET members_types = concat_ws(
    ';',
    members_types,
    (SELECT string_agg(distinct osm_pistes_area.type::text, ';')
        FROM osm_pistes_area
        WHERE ST_Intersects(osm_pistes_area.geometry,test.geometry)
    )
);
UPDATE test SET members_types = concat_ws(
    ';',
    members_types,
    (SELECT string_agg(distinct osm_sport_ways.type::text, ';')
        FROM osm_sport_ways
        WHERE ST_Intersects(osm_sport_ways.geometry,test.geometry)
    )
);
UPDATE test SET members_types = concat_ws(
    ';',
    members_types,
    (SELECT string_agg(distinct osm_sport_nodes.type::text, ';')
        FROM osm_sport_nodes
        WHERE ST_Intersects(osm_sport_nodes.geometry,test.geometry)
    )
);
```